# How to call DLL function in vbscript

Tags: com, dll, function, vbscript

I am writing VB script in which I have to call a function of a COM DLL. The function which I want to use is in structure and thus I want to create the object of that structure to access the required function.

e.g.
I have a dll 'BasicCom.dll', in which

```
struct abc
{
    bool xyz();
}
```

Now I want to call xyz(). Does anyone have any idea, how to deal with such call in Vb script?

Comment: What language is the COM dll written in, are you sure its a structure?  COM has no mechism to treat a structure as something that may have methods.

Comment: That does not look like a COM function at all.  Calling functions in a C++ program like this is not supported.

Comment: My COM DLL is written in C++, in which there is C++ struct and methods declared..

Answer (score 2):

Hans's comment is correct. This is a pure C++ method, not a method of a COM class. You cannot call it from VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

[VBScript CreateObject Function](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_createobject.asp)

> The CreateObject function creates an
>   object of a specified type.

**Syntax**

```
CreateObject(servername.typename[,location])
```

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score -1):

You should to register it as COM+ component (run `REGSVR32 BasicCom.dll`) and do:

```
Set yourClass = CreateObject("BasicCom.Abc") ''// Should be ProjectName.ClassName
returnValue = yourClass.xyz()
```

Comment: Regsvr32 merely registers the COM component.  COM+ is something different which (among other things) allows for a COM component to hosted in another process.  COM+ is not needed in this scenario.